# Webform Fields not hidden anymore after update to 8.x-5.0-rc19

Tags: 8, webforms

After updating to Webform 8.x-5.0-rc19 fields that should be visible only after filling another field, are instead always visible. I guess this has something to do with "Elements, containers, and pages that are hidden using conditional logic will have their submission data cleared when a webform is submitted" (https://www.drupal.org/node/2956589), but I do not understand how.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be reported in the Webform issue queue on drupal.org

Comment: Yes, this is a Drupal 8.6.x+ core issue. The problem is that most people are discovering this issue via the Webform module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [#states breaks when OR is used](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2995570)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can confirm that the patch fixes my problem

Comment: @Det Then what is stopping you from marking this answer as accepted? Which is what is expected from you in that case?